# How to use smoke for POJO in project with Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

As I know Dart-Polymer uses its own transformer to configure static smoke configuration (polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart)
and it gets only classes with @CustomTag annotation.

I want to use smoke with my POJO classes. I've tried some transformer examples, but, as I can see, its generates *_bootstrap.html files, as Polymer does, so its conflicting.

How I can configure (append) static smoke configuration for my POJO classes.
Is here copy-pasting entire polymer's transforming infrastructure to my project and change it my way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I am pretty sure you can't configure smoke more than once, so unless polymer provided an explicit hook or something you might be out of luck...

You could try using the [reflectable](https://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable) package, but it hasn't actually been published yet and doesn't have full coverage over the mirrors api. It does let you reflect on class declarations and invoke methods today though, which might be all you need? You would have to clone it and use a path dependency since the repo layout isn't compatible with git dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately, it neither want to get polymer's entry points (list web/index.html), neither my classes that I need to reflect:
`Could not find a main method in File "<PROJDIR>/lib/src/widgets/widgets.dart". Skipping.`